# Saving files to different folder

Tags: python, pandas, path, save-as, os.path

I´m trying to save converted excel files from different paths, to the same folder.
How can I pass the path to the function correctly?
Now what is happening is that it is attaching the original path to the save path I have given to the function.

So my solution was:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import csv, json
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path
import os, os.path
import errno

destination_path = "C:\\csv_files"

all_paths = [r"C:\\PLM\\PML.xlsx",r"C:\\TMR\\TMR.xlsx",r"C:\\PLM\\PLM.xlsx"]
```

Create variable to store tuple list

```
all_items = []
```

Create tuple list with file path and file name without extension

```
def getFileName():

for paths in all_paths:
    all_items.append((paths , paths.split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0]))
```

Convert given files by iterating through tuple list and pass destination folder.

```
def convertFiles():

for item in all_items:
    read_file = pd.read_excel(item[0], 'Relatório - DADOS', index_col=None, engine='openpyxl')
    read_file.to_csv(destination_path + "\\"+ item[1] + ".csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: you need to create those paths first. do it just after the first loop, where you iterate the paths

Comment: Unless you're in that directory, python won't recognise that `excel_files` exists. Otherwise use `__file__` and make paths based on that?

Comment: Hi NelsonGon, @Sembei thanks for the input. Changed the code with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure the save folder exists by adding this line before the outer `for` loop:

```
Path(save_path).mkdir(exist_ok=True)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir).